# Inyección de dependencia fallido con spring en Java. NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, jpa, ejb

He creado un proyecto Java en spring boot, el cual exponga un EJB que pueda ser accedido de forma remota. Sin embargo, en el momento de hacer un llamado a un método dentro de la implementación, lanza un nullpointerexception debido a que la dependencia del JPA repository no fue inyectada. Aquí abajo las clases.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class MainApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(MainApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Aquí la implementación:

```
@Service
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
@Stateless(name = "IServiceEJB ", mappedName = "IServiceEJB ")
@Remote
public class ServiceEJBImpl implements IServiceEJB {

    @Autowired
    public EmpresaRepository empresaRepository;

    public void registra(Empresa empresa) throws EmpresaException {

        try{
            empresaRepository.save(empresa);     <-- Aqui marca NullPointerException
        }catch (Exception e ){
            System.out.println("Error al registrar en BD");
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.getCause();
        }
    
    }
}
```

Aquí el entity:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(Id.class)
@Table(name = "empresa_table")
public class EmpresaDAO implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String tipoTransaccion;

    @Column(name = "nombre_empresa")
    private Integer nombreEmpresa;

--Setters y getters--

}
```

Aquí la interface:

```
@Repository
public interface EmpresaRepository extends JpaRepository<EmpresaDAO, Id> {

    String findByNombre(String nombre);
    Integer findById(Integer id);

}
```

Sin embargo, al invocar el EJB que desplegué en un WAR en JBoss lanza nullpointerException al llamar al método "save" de empresaRepository

Entiendo que puede ser que no este logrando hacer la inyección de la dependencia de forma correcta, pero no he podido dar con la solución. ¿Puede alguien ayudarme con esto?

Comment: cual es el error que te marca exactamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que en el repository haces referencia a EmpresaDAO. Sin embargo en el servicio al guardar estas pasando como parámetro un objecto de la clase Empresa (el repositorio debe estar esperando un EmpresaDAO). No hay un save hecho que acepte objetos Empresa y probablemente ese sea el error.